# Malware script in database post table only?

Tags: security, hacked

How can java script be visible in phpmyadmin posts but not visible within the wordpress environment??

Been struggling to clean a wordpress site after an annoying hack which popsup ads and redirects.

Used a couple of security plugins to clean up infected files but..

When I check the posts table in phpmyadmin I can see there is still some javascript added to the end of many posts & pages, but visiting the live page or editing the page in wordpress - I can't find this script at all?

Thanks